# I wanted to create a search bar, but there are some errors. Code is as below

Tags: flutter, class, search, searchbar

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  SearchBar searchBar;

  AppBar buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return new AppBar(
      title: new Text('My Home Page'),
      actions: [searchBar.getSearchAction(context)]
    );
  }  

  _MyHomePageState() {
    searchBar = new SearchBar(
      inBar: false,
      setState: setState,
      onSubmitted: print,
      buildDefaultAppBar: buildAppBar
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: searchBar.build(context)
    );
  }
}
```

Errors: Classes can only extend other classes. The name 'MyHomePage' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. Classes can't be declared inside other classes. Expected to find '}'. The declaration '_MyHomePageState' isn't referenced.

Comment: ???Please help!

Comment: Can you show us the SearcBar class ?

Comment: Please post complete code. Where is your `MyHomePage` class?

Comment: Hello all, I just used the code in the searchbar example: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_search_bar/versions/3.0.0-dev.1. You scroll down to the bottom in the first section (Readme). Isn't the code complete?